# I have a string of xml to post to API that has multiple elements but only posts the first element then stops

Tags: python, xml, api

I am new to python and have been grinding on this automation task for 2 months before posting this...I just hit a wall.

I have successfully pulled rows from excel sheet and created a variable called payload which is a string of xml. I need to make a post of this string to an api.  It connects and successfully posts the only the first set of elements to the api and stops.  I cant seem to figure out how to get it to loop through all of the payload and post each set of elements till done.

I am getting all the successful codes that i connected and posted correctly but again its just posting the first instance and stopping

This is what payload looks like as per sites recommendation

```
<request>
   <serviceRequestAddLabor>
     <serviceRequestId>1009</serviceRequestId>
     <userId>40887</userId>
     <dateWorked>2019.06.18 07:00 PM</dateWorked>
     <duration>8</duration>
     <itemNo>labor</itemNo>
     <comment>Worked on revolving doors</comment>
   </serviceRequestAddLabor>

   <serviceRequestAddLabor>
     <serviceRequestId>1009</serviceRequestId>
     <userId>64730</userId>
     <dateWorked>2019.06.18 07:00 PM</dateWorked>
     <duration>8</duration>
     <itemNo>labor</itemNo>
     <comment>Worked on revolving doors</comment>
   </serviceRequestAddLabor>

   <serviceRequestAddLabor>
     <serviceRequestId>1009</serviceRequestId>
     <userId>51422</userId>
     <dateWorked>2019.06.18 07:00 PM</dateWorked>
     <duration>8</duration>
     <itemNo>labor</itemNo>
     <comment>Worked on revolving doors</comment>
   </serviceRequestAddLabor>
</request>
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

sched = pd.read_excel('nightreportapitest.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols=[0,1,3,4,7,11], index=0)

def to_xml(row):
    xmlstring = ['   <serviceRequestAddLabor>']
    for field in row.index:
        xmlstring.append('     <{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(field, row[field]))
    xmlstring.append('   </serviceRequestAddLabor>\n')
    return '\n'.join(xmlstring,)

x = '\n'.join(sched.apply(to_xml, axis=1))
payload = []
open_request = '<request>'
close_request = '</request>'
payload.append(open_request)
payload.append(x)
payload.append(close_request)
payload = [i.replace('"', '') for i in payload]
payload = '\n'.join(payload)

url = "https://app.bluefolder.com/api/2.0/serviceRequests/addLabor.aspx"
headers = {
     'authorization': "xxxxxxxxxxx",
     'cache-control': "no-cache"
     }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers = headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the endpoint that you are submitting the XML to? It may be an issue at their end

Comment: After a quick scan of bluefolders API docs, they don't state anywhere that they support multiple service requests in one payload. Maybe try splitting this up into multiple requests

Comment: so @IainShelvington maybe earlier in code as I pull a row from the excel sheet i should post it one by one is some loop setup